# SpeechRecognizer is not listening , Getting no response

Tags: android

```
    RecognitionListener recognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() { .. }
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);

    final Intent speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,"en-US");
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something");
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en-US");
```

Then OnClick event I am doing :

```
    micButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!isListening)
            {
                isListening = true;
                micButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_24);
                editText.setHint("mic clicked");
                speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
            }
            else {
                speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                editText.setHint("touch end");
                isListening = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying to listen on the mic button click but I am getting no response from SpeechRecognizer while running on the device after giving permissions to the app. What could be the reasons for this? Please help

Answer (score 2):

it turns out `SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable()` was false. Due to this, `speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);` was not doing anything.

After inserting the below lines in the manifest file, solved the issue

```
<!--suppress AndroidElementNotAllowed -->
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

add these line outside the application tag and
now `SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable()` would return true.